# can not ping linux hostname from windows

Tags: ping, samba

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, windows 7 with a domain.

Can do:

ping windows 7 hostname from ubuntu

ping ubuntu ip from windows

nbtstat -a ubuntu ip will show ubuntu hostname.

Can't do:

ping ubuntu hostname from windows.

I have checked samba/winbind, they seems OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add an **A** record for Ubuntu either in your domain's nameserver or in your Windows' host file?